# R: Factor analysis scores differ from calculation with factor loadings (psych)

Tags: r, psych, factor-analysis

I did a factor analysis with 3 items using fa() from psych package:

```
fa.model <- fa(grass.factors,
               nfactors = 1,
               n.obs = nrow(grass.factors),
               SMC = TRUE,
               fm = 'ml')
```

I got the following factor loadings:

```
Loadings:
       ML1  
Var1  0.997
Var2  0.790
Var3  0.603
```

As I understand the formula to calculate the scores from hand is:

> Score = Var1 * 0.997 + Var2 * 0.790 + Var3 * 0.603

The first score of the model is -1.57553340.
But when I wanted to check that score using the formula above:

> -1584.939 = 0.7223548 * 0.997 + 0.06438407 * 0.790 + (-2629.7013) * 0.603

What do I miss here?

Comment: If `Var` is the variable, why not compute `Var %*% fa.model$loadings` and see if your computation gives the same value? Also, were the variables used as is or were z-scores computed and passed to `fa`?

Comment: @RuiBarradas The variables were passed to fa() as they were. I did no further computations.

Comment: Without data it's not possible to tell, your hand computation seems right.

Comment: @RuiBarradas I’ve uploaded the data for you here: http://www.sharecsv.com/s/07c94749d6033ac5aae3a046d9dfd2c5/grass.csv I hope it helps.

Comment: The only thing wrong with your hand computation is that you are using rounded values for the first row of the data set. With the actual value the score is -1586.099. Try `Scores <- as.matrix(grass.factor) %*% fa.model$loadings; head(Scores)` Where does that *first score of the model* come from? Are you fitting the same model (rotations come to mind)?

Comment: @RuiBarradas But -1586.099 is still far off the scores value. The value comes from the first row of fa.modell$scores.

Comment: OK, I believe `help('factor.scores')` explains what you want to know. I have just seen the function's code and it is also worth taking a look, but it's not trivial to follow it.